# Optimizing Tor Browser Performance on Raspberry Pi 3: Dependencies and Configuration

Tags: browser, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, vpn, tor

What are the necessary dependencies needed for installing Tor Browser on a Raspberry Pi 3? Are there any performance concerns when using Tor Browser on this device, and if there are, what can be done to enhance its performance? I have installed the latest version using the terminal, but it prompts for an additional processor and the Tor Browser fails to run. What steps can be taken to configure it for a Raspberry Pi 3 that utilizes amrhf?